# Suggest or choose a theme for the 2014 Winter GDSE Game Jam!

Tags: discussion, gamejam-2014-winter

Suggest a theme if you have one on your mind, upvote the themes that have already been suggested and you like, and downvote those that you do not like. I'll add some to get us started.

Format (with Byte's filler text that I shamelessly stole, to get answers to meet length criteria):

```
Theme Name
-
Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.
```

Comment: Choosing random from the top 5 or what?

Comment: That was suggested yes. Seems like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Time is broken.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 18):

### Chain reaction.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 17):

### Replication.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 9):

### Amplify.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 8):

### Glitches

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 8):

### Survival of the fittest.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 8):

### Rules are made to be broken.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 7):

### Sandbox

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 7):

### Swarm

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 7):

### Abnormal Inputs

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 7):

### Rage Quit

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 6):

### Build It

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 5):

### Mad scientist.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 4):

## **Lights and Visibility**

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 4):

### Trust no one.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 4):

### Expect the Unexpected.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 4):

### Sub zero

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 4):

### Fractals

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

### Reap what you sow.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

### Education.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

### Organic vs machine.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

### Wireframe

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 2):

### It's Alive!

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 2):

### You are what you eat

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 2):

### Reticulating splines.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 2):

### Time Travelling Snowmen

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 2):

### Benefits of Failure

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

### Angry machines

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

### States of matter.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

## **Dreams**

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

### Bigger on the inside.

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

### Todders

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

## Rhythm and Rhyme

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

## Forgetfulness

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

### Hacking

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -1):

### Gotta collect 'em all!

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -1):

### World Peace

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -1):

### Dark and Light

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -1):

### Baby, it's cold outside

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -1):

## **Local Multiplayer**

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -1):

### Lack of snow

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -1):

### Less is more

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -2):

### Suicide

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -2):

### Save the world

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -3):

### 1999 Mode

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -4):

### Miami Vice

Vote up the themes you want; vote down the themes you don't.